# Dealing duplicate image data in React Native

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, react-native, redux

I'm building 'Comments Detail page' which is a list view for comments in a single post (basically it's just facebook comments page).

I generated this JSON response data below, and as you can see, there are duplicate image urls. It means that if same user comments 100 times on a post, it needs to get image data from AWS 100 times rather than 1 time.

Maybe it's over-engineering? How do you guys deal with this?

Here is JSON data

```
{
    "comments": [{
        "id": 4,
        "user": {
            "image": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com:443/-",
            "id": 1,
            "username": "jbaek73"
        },
        "content": "Edited!",
        "publish": "2017-09-18T12:11:41.002838Z",
        "updated": "2017-09-19T08:16:25.408756Z",
        "reply_count": 1
    },
    {
        "id": 13,
        "user": {
            "image": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com:443/-",
            "id": 1,
            "username": "jbaek73"
        },
        "content": "Neaa!",
        "publish": "2017-09-18T14:12:51.876523Z",
        "updated": "2017-09-18T14:12:51.876600Z",
        "reply_count": 0
    },
    {
        "id": 14,
        "user": {
            "image": "https://xxx.s3.amazonaws.com:443/random",
            "id": 5,
            "username": "koreana"
        },
        "content": "Newa!",
        "publish": "2017-09-19T08:16:35.190351Z",
        "updated": "2017-09-19T08:16:35.190398Z",
        "reply_count": 0
    },
```

Comment: Your browser will cache the image the first time, it won't need to fetch it 100 times

Comment: @Mikkel That would be wonderful. Will my browser(iOS and ANdroid) do it automatilcally? Have you read any article about it??? How did you know that?

Comment: These things are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, i would create an image object with all the required images and the user id as key:

```
randomFuntionName() { //you can call after you get your json
 var img = []

 comments.forEach((element) => { //comments are comming from your json btw
  if (img[element.user.id] == null) {
    img[element.user.id] = require(element.user.image)
  }
 })
 this.setState({img})
}

render() {
  //this part is only for example, you need to dynamicaly change userID
  return (<Image source={this.state.img[userId]}/>)
}
```

This should do the work, but didn't tested it in app.